# How can you await a Task when you can't await

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm developing a Windows 8 Runtime Component so the public interface can't contain `Task<T>` as it's not a windows runtime type.

This means I can't mark the method as `async` and can't `await` the `private async` methods in my library. This is leading to some confusion about how to handle my application logic.

This is how I'd do what I want synchronously.

```
Result r = TryGetAuthResultFromFile();
if(r != null)
{
    return r;
}

r = GetAuthResultFromWebAuthenticationBroker();
return r;
```

The problem is that TryGetResultFrom file are `async Task<Result>` methods and the method that's returning r is returning `IAsyncOperation<Result>`

I've tried this (this isn't complete code but the theory can be seen, handle the results in continuations and return them, I'd have to do some frigging of results to IAsyncOperation types).

```
TryGetAuthResultFromFile().ContinueWith(x=>
{
    if(x.Result != null)
    {
        return x.result;
    }

    GetAuthResultFromWebAuthenticationBroker().ContinueWith(y=>
    {
        return y.Result;
    });
});
```

The problem with this is that the `WebAuthenticationBroker` doesn't seem work if it's not being called from the UI thread. It throws a helpful `NotImplementedException` without a useful error message.

How can I call `TryGetAuthResultFromFile` then wait for the result, then call `GetAuthResultFromWebAuthenticationBroker`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your interface can't use `Task`/`Task<T>`, but it can use `IAsyncAction`/`IAsyncOperation<T>`.

Your implementation can use `Task`/`Task<T>` if you have a wrapper that calls `AsAsyncAction`/`AsAsyncOperation`/`AsyncInfo.Run` as appropriate.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
  IAsyncOperation<MyResult> MyMethod();
}

public sealed class MyClass: IMyInterface
{
  private async Task<MyResult> MyMethodAsync()
  {
    var r = await TryGetAuthResultFromFileAsync();
    if (r != null)
      return r;
    return await GetAuthResultFromAuthenticationBrokerAsync();
  }

  public IAsyncOperation<MyResult> MyMethod()
  {
    return MyMethodAsync().AsAsyncOperation();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already used this technique somewhere else and it does exactly what I need. I'm not sure why I didn't spot the obvious solution, home time I think.